Agentforce cannot view external link
I built an agent that needs to access an authenticated link stored in the Salesforce field. This link contains a token tied to the Salesforce record and navigates to the client's website. I built an agent action using a prompt template to access the website's content but received a response

I'm unable to access external websites or links. Therefore, I cannot
gather the specific information from the provided link.

The website might have robots.txt restriction that prevents automated systems or bots to view the content directly. Any advice or workaround you can suggest?
Accessing the link directly is necessary because the website reflects real-time updates, while data synchronization with SF is one-day delayed.
